# How to properly expose underlying template type to be used as type

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, using

I have some string class `IMyString` and that can be either wstring or normal string. It has two derivations `MyString` and `MWString`. If a templated code wants to accept both, it currently needs both the string type argument and char type argument. I wanted to change that.

This is my code:

```
// This string doesn't work, it's just an example
template <typename CharType, typename Derived>
class IMyString
{
public:
  // Define value type so that it can ba accessed by other templates (does not work)
  using ValueType = typename CharType;

  const CharType* c_str() const { return rawData; }
  // Does not actually do the adition for brevity, just imagine it instead
  Derived&& operator+(const CharType* moreData) const { return Derived(/*should add my own data here and also copy everything etc*/moreData); }

protected:
  IMyString(const CharType* rawData) : rawData(rawData) {}

  const CharType* rawData = nullptr;
};

// Normal string
class MyString : public IMyString<char, MyString>
{
public:
  MyString(const char* data) : IMyString(data) {}

};

// Wide char string
class MyWString : public IMyString<wchar_t, MyString>
{
public:
  MyWString(const wchar_t* data) : IMyString(data) {}

};

// Method that doesn't really do anything actually
template <typename StringType>
// I want to be able to use the value type directly as type
void DoSomethingWithAnyString(StringType string, const StringType::ValueType* dataToAdd)
{
  StringType string2 = string + dataToAdd;
  // even if the addition worked, it has no effect because the value is not returned
}

int main()
{
  MyString someString("Hello");
  DoSomethingWithAnyString(someString, " world!");
}
```

GCC error I get now:

```
UnderlyingTemplateType.cpp:9:30: error: expected nested-name-specifier before 'CharType'
   using ValueType = typename CharType;
```

But when I remove typename, that's an error too:

```
UnderlyingTemplateType.cpp:40:56: error: need 'typename' before 'StringType::ValueType' because 'StringType' is a dependent scope
 void DoSomethingWithAnyString(StringType string, const StringType::ValueType* dataToAdd)
```

How to do this correctly? I want to use `IMyString::ValueType` as I would if it was a nested class/struct/enum.

I can see that this works, but I'd rather not write `typename` everywhere I use the `ValueType`:

```
// Method that doesn't really do anything actually
template <typename StringType>
// I want to be able to use the value type directly as type
void DoSomethingWithAnyString(StringType string, const typename StringType::ValueType* dataToAdd)
{
  StringType string2 = string + dataToAdd;
  // even if the addition worked, it has no effect because the value is not returned
}
```

Is there a concise definition that allows the `ValueType` to act as a real type?

Comment: What the error tells you to write is `const typename StringType::ValueType* dataToAdd`, because `StringType` is opaque to the parser at that point.

Comment: @Quentin Can that requirement be avoided somehow by defining ValueType differently? Having to write typename in every use seems annoying and also distracting as it isn't usual sight in variable names.

Comment: No, but you may define `template <class StringType> using ValueType = typename StringType::ValueType`, then use `ValueType<StringType>` in your code.

Comment: Do both the things that the errors say...?

Comment: @TomášZato-ReinstateMonica In blockscope you could define a new alias. In your example you could use a second template parameter `typename ValueType = typename StringType::ValueType`.

Comment: @super That's the best I have now and what I ended up committing, but I'm still curious if there's a purely in-class solution

Answer (score 0):

The best you can do is something like that - write helper alias that wraps the despised typename. [Live example](https://godbolt.org/z/hVNXCf)

```cpp
template<class T>
using char_t = typename T::ValueType;

// Method that doesn't really do anything actually
template <typename StringType>
// I want to be able to use the value type directly as type
void DoSomethingWithAnyString(StringType string, const char_t<StringType>* dataToAdd)
{
  StringType string2 = string + dataToAdd;
  // even if the addition worked, it has no effect because the value is not returned
}
```

Comment: I tried to do a similar thing within the `IMyString` directly, but I still couldn't use `StringType::char_type`. I am confused why somehow sometimes repeating the typename works and sometimes not.

Comment: @TomášZato-ReinstateMonica well, you just have to accept that `so the standard sayeth` :P. More seroiusly - inside the template you can't use `typename` since it is not depndent name yet